# Can't Find Adobe Source Code Pro Font with "Regular" Weight after Installation?

Tags: 14.04, fonts

I installed the font Source Code Pro by copying the fonts into `/usr/share/fonts`. However, now whenever I want to use the font, I cannot find the "Regular" weight of the font. There seems to be two "Medium" weight of the font, and when I type in "Source Code Pro Regular", the Medium weighted font gets shown in the search results, and it seems to indeed display the medium weight. I had to remove the files `SourceCodePro-Medium.otf` and `SourceCodePro-Mediumlt.otf` from the font folder and rebuild the cache in order to use the regular version of the font normally. Why is that happening and how can I deal with it?

[image: The font selection menu]